# Get-adgroupmember with Recursive parameter but I need to display the nested group name that users below to

Tags: powershell, active-directory

**I have a script that will list AD groups’ members and exported to CSV file.
AD group name will show in one column and domain\user will show in another column but some AD groups have nested AD groups so I used -Recursive but now it will show all nested AD groups members under the main AD group not under the nested AD group that they belong to. I am trying to find a way to show the name of the nested group in another column? Any help will be appropriated :)

```
$objForest = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest()
$DomainList = @($objForest.Domains | Select-Object Name)
$Domains = $DomainList | ForEach-Object { $_.Name }

foreach($Domain in ($Domains)) {
    $Groups = Import-Csv C:\ad.csv

    $Table = @()

    $Record = @{
        "Group Name" = ""
        "Name" = ""
        #"Username" = ""
        "domain" = ""
    }

    foreach ($Group in $Groups) {

        $Arrayofmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group.groupad -Server $Domain -Recursive |
            Select-Object name, samaccountname, distinguishedName

        foreach ($Member in $Arrayofmembers) {
            $username = $Member.samaccountname
            $distinguishedName = $Member.distinguishedName
            $dc = [regex]::Match($distinguishedName,'DC=([^,|$]+)').Groups[1].Value    
            $domainuser = '{0}\{1}' -f $dc, $username
            $Record."Group Name" = $Group.ad
            $Record."Name" = $Member.name
            $Record."Domain" = $domainuser
            $objRecord = New-Object PSObject -Property $Record
            $Table += $objrecord
        }
    }
}

$Table | Export-Csv "C:\SecurityGroups01.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```